# UI TableView cell opening a new view with multiple data using coredata in swift

Tags: iphone, swift, uitableview, core-data, uiviewcontroller

as a beginner in iOS and Swift, I have a project that has to have a tableview with multiple cells, in which every cell contains several data types. i.e. Strings, dates etc., where in one view controller, there is the table view for viewing the cells, the second view controller is for creating a cell and entering the data, and the third view is for displaying the same data when clicking the cell. I've decided to store all of that using coredata since I was told it's most efficient and simple for beginners. I've used several tutorials on this matter but none of them handle this type of problem I have. Best example is how the *Contact list* works on iOS.
The code I've done so far is this:

```
 var titleCellList = [NSManagedObject]()
 var infoCellList = [NSManagedObject]()

class CellsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource,    UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet var cellsTableView: UITableView!

//MARK: Default Functions

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    title = "\"Lists\""
    cellsTableView.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

// MARK: UITableViewDataSource

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return TitleCellList.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! UITableViewCell
        let cellTitle = titleCellList[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = cellTitle.valueForKey("title") as? String

        return cell
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    cellsTableView.reloadData()
}
```

//MARK: Storing CoreData

```
 func saveName(name: String) {
    //1
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    //2
    let entity =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("Data", inManagedObjectContext: managedContext)
    let title = NSManagedObject(entity: entity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext:managedContext)

    //3
    title.setValue(name, forKey: "title")

    //4
    var error: NSError?
    if !managedContext.save(&error) {
        println("Could not save \(error), \(error?.userInfo)")
    }
    //5
    titleCellList.append(title)
}
```

//MARK: Fetching CoreData

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    //1
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let managedContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext!

    //2
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName:"Data")

    //3
    var error: NSError?
    let fetchedResults = managedContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &error) as? [NSManagedObject]

    if let results = fetchedResults {
        titleCellList = results
    } else {
        println("Could not fetch \(error), \(error!.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

//    MARK: Table Editing Methods

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {

            let appDel:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
            let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!
            context.deleteObject(titleCellList[indexPath.row] as NSManagedObject)
            titleCellList.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            context.save(nil)

            cellsTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

        let row = indexPath.row
        println("Row: \(row)")

        println(titleCellList[row])
        performSegueWithIdentifier("checkCellSegue", sender: self)
    }
```

**Second View Controller (the one for creating a cell with data)**

```
class AddNewViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {


@IBOutlet var titleTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var shortInfoTextView: UITextView!

//MARK: Default Functions

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.titleTextField.delegate = self


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

@IBAction func addDataButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {

    if titleTextField.text != ""  {
    CellsViewController().saveName(titleTextField.text)
    titleTextField.text = ""
    shortInfoTextView.text = ""
        println("New title Added!")
    }else {
        println("No empty titles allowed!")
    }
}
```

Now, most of this code is from a tutorial, and when I tried adding other data entity's, it didn't work. In the datamodel I currently have only 1 entity named "Data" which contains 4 models. So, to sum it up, I need to store 4 data models in one entity and load them on a different view controller when clicking on a cell which of course, has a title that the user wrote. And just to note, I've spent hours searching online for an answer so this is my last line so to say.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It sounds like you need to Entities with a relationship between them. Something like `Title` -*`Info` where the relationship is one-to-many, however without  more information on exactly what your model is it's rather difficult to provide any assistance.  Provide an explanation of the business problem you are trying to solve, i.e what are the real world objects your data is trying to represent.

Comment: When creating a new data, user enters a title for the cell, the info which is a textview, a timer and a date. On the first view the cell displays the title, and once it's clicked, it opens another view which loads the same data: cell title, info, timer and date (which are editable if needed)

Comment: OK well that's a single entity with fields for title, text, timer(int) and a date so use a UITableView, NSFetchedResultsController  and NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate methods to present the tableView and then a single DetailsView for editing the selected object.  The sample apps here have examples of doing exactly that http://ossh.com.au/design-and-technology/software-development/sample-library-style-ios-core-data-app-with-icloud-integration/

Comment: Hmm, well, thanks but like I said, I am new to iOS and this...well, it's senior level, covers way more grounds than I need nor can I understand. I could try understanding this but it's gonna take me hours...btw I've downloaded the project but it's only OSX and in Obj-C...

Comment: You might have to look around for a Swift equivalent but you should be able to see the structure and then just convert to the Swift API, for the most part its a 1-1 conversion.  There are two versions, one is OSX and the other is iOS.  Download the iOS one and look at the CompanyViewController and the CompanyDetailViewController classes.

Comment: I have started a repository for a pure Swift 2.0 version of the sample apps above.  Have a look at the initial version as it has a very basic Master-Detail implementation from the XCode template. I try an update this over time.  https://github.com/duncangroenewald/Core-Data-Sample-App

Comment: Wow Duncan...this looks really nice :) , but um...I am afraid I won't be able to test it since my company is on hold for xcode 7 beta and swift 2.0, but I like your entry a lot since you covered iCloud with CoreData, which is not easily found. I've managed to solve my issue in the meantime, which I will post right bellow. But again, kudos on the sample app and I will continue to track your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is the one approach I used on this little issue. I basically just pass arguments with the prepareForSegue method, and inside of it I just pass the data I want to use in the other class/VC.

The Code:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    // Setter for Second VC, destination path --> var declarations in Second VC

    if segue.identifier == "checkCellSegue" {
        let destination = segue.destinationViewController as! SecondViewController
        if let indexPath = self.tableView?.indexPathForCell(sender as! UITableViewCell) {
            let object = fetchedResultsController?.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? Data
            destination.cellTitle = object?.cellTitle
            destination.textViewInfo = object?.textViewInfo
            destination.timerValue = object?.timerValue

        }
    }
```

So, first we declare the destination which is the name of our Second VC or whatever you named it. Then, since I am accessing data trough a TableView cell we need to fetch my CoreData Entity with the indexPath. After that the final declaration is the Model Class which has all the data values from the entity, which will work like a singleton.

```
destination.cellTitle // --> in the 2.nd VC we declared a new var called cellTitle, var cellTitle:String

object?.cellTitle  // --> in the model class "Data.swift" the declaration is @NSManaged var cellTitle:String
```

So, thats it. I am still a little newbie on iOS so if there are any mistakes, just say so.